# catch MySql trigger on the activerecord level

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, triggers

I develop project on Ruby using Rails4. I have two mysql tables A and B, also I have MySql trigger which update column value of B table when I update column from A table, using for example MySql client, not by backend. Can I catch update event of B table on the backend using activerecord or anything else solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.** Triggers don't produce exceptions or anything else that you can catch from a higher level.

Embedding logic into the database is against "the Rails way", which would have been to use the Model to set up such operations, by the way.